# Highlight code SQL Style rather than Stackoverflow style

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I ask [Storing date as integer (numeric), what are the advantages](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15645/storing-date-as-integer-numeric-what-are-the-advantages) here. Look at the code styling, it does not look that professional and easy to grasp.

[image]

Vs

[image]

on [this site](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic803419-338-1.aspx). Notice how the code is properly highlighted SQL Style.

Shouldn't we style all the code SQL style too so it is easy to grasp, more friendly and look more professional?

Comment: "it does not look that professional and easy to grasp." I think I prefer ours!

Comment: I definitely like sql style, more readable.

Comment: by 'sql style' do you mean SSMS style?

Comment: SE's syntax hilighting is done through a third party application and you can hint it.  Take a look at [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9471/2092) for an example.  Beyond that, we don't have all that much control.

Comment: Technically we have a lot of control. We just have to show good reason

Comment: @JackDouglas, right SSMS style but I do not know from oracle ppl and their insight will be helpful. **@ concerned** the  formatting looks regular to me? Am I missing something.

Comment: I get blue and grey in SQL Developer (Oracle tool bit like SSMS) - no fancy colours.

Comment: What is "SQL style"? Purple for functions, Red for dates, Blue for keywords, etc? Even in your example, I see no colourization of integers or variables.

Comment: also in case you don't know a downvote here on meta meand 'I don't agree' rather than 'Its a bad question'

Comment: @JackDouglas, disagree even though I upvoted your last comment. If a question is about discussion only, what does the downvote means in that case? I do not agree?

Comment: You asked "Shouldn't we style all the code SQL style too so it is easy to grasp, more friendly and look more professional?", a downvote on the question means "No, I don't think we should, at least not the way your example shows". Comments are voted on as normal of course...

Comment: of course, folk vote how they please - I'm just saying what is generally true AFAIK :-)

Comment: Hover over the downvote and read: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"

Comment: @jcolebrand, that is helpful. And yes it does mean it is a good question vs a bad question rather than I agree vs I dont agree. If you want to disagree or agree, there is where comments and answers come in.

Comment: @JackDouglas Unfortunately that is promoted even in the tool tips for voting on meta.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites/104398#104398

Comment: Aye, this is the proper strategy. But in this case, when people are downvoting this Q, they are saying "I don't think this change is worth implementing/asking for"

Comment: Up/Down vote is definitely one way of saying I agree/Do not agree. But this is not the only way to vote it. @LeighRiffel link explains it really well. JeffAtwood answer is the best there and the most negatively voted too. So about this question, I may upvote it, not because I agree but I think it is a good question.

Comment: Oops, I meant that **isn't** promoted even in the tool tips.

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean "properly highlighted sql style"? You're not very helpful with that, unless you mean "Everything should be formatted like Microsoft SQL Server does things.

What the site uses, and what everyone agrees is "just right" is http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ which is a "industry standard colorization module". Now, it could be argued that there needs to be a different coloration for SQL code, however, I challenge you to tell me what's the right coloration for MySQL or PLSQL. Because those don't use SSMS.

As for mandatory code-block capitalization ... why should the system auto-correct anything you type in? That's your job, to provide us with the code you're using. If you want to use a T-SQL pretty printer, that will reflow your code, you're welcome to, and I can suggest the add-in I currently use, but that won't win you brownie points with anyone here. We care about code we can read, not what the colors are.

Comment: Will rephrase it. But part of is discussion also because I do not know everything. There is no standard editor for MYSQL that uses color scheme so I would skip on any SQL which does not have a dedicated editor. **2**. We should not be capitalizing the code. This is the poster job. We only need to format it SQL style. It helps in readability a lot. The fact is most of the code here will be SQL, this would be helpful for this professional site. *Please allow me some time to make edits - @work* **Also an insight from oracle ppl will be helpful. I don't know how they highlight code**.

Comment: You're welcome to make edits, you probably saw my initial response and not my edited one? :-\

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but capitalization of keywords is part of (a level of) SQL standard, isn't it?

Comment: @jcolebrand, re-read. `Properly highlighted sql style`, probably means `to adhere to some standards that is used in SQL world, most common would by SSMS and I am sure ppl wont have problem with it`. I have not get a chance to use the referenced google syntax highlighting but I have used a couple in Wordpress. The rule is, the color should be bright enough. *Our colors are faint, hard to distinguish and too subtle*. Importantly our site is only for SQL ppl so it would be better to stick to some kind of sql standard rather than go generic.

Comment: I challenge "most common would be SSMS" because Oracle is a huge player. I mean, HUGE. So ... Let's not use SSMS as our only basis.

Comment: I re-challenge with PHPMyAdmin :)

Comment: However, now you're coming to the crux of your suggestion: "the colors are too faint". I don't know if you've noticed, the entire site is faint. Can you suggest something that pops better that doesn't actively have negative contrast? We do have a professional designer that has worked on the site here, and as a professional designer (not a DBA) he felt this was a good mix of readability and "what works for the masses". But if you can make objective style changes, I'm sure he's all for that.

Comment: I agree on "the whole site is faint" observation.

Answer (score 4):

**Not in Favor**

In practice there is no standard for SQL syntax highlighting.  You might be able to define a standard for one tool on one database platform without any customization, but this seems too narrow to be useful.

When you can't please everyone (or even most people) it makes sense to choose something subtle that can be more easily ignored if the effect is undesirable yet provides enough of a visual difference to be useful.  I think our current syntax highlighting does that very well.

Sure in my mind it could be improved on, but mostly in the way of making it similar to one of the several syntax highlighters I use every day.  While this might make it better for some people, just as many (or more) would see it as worse.

That being said, I am not opposed to changes in our syntax highlighter particularly if the specific change can be identified.  However, I am not in favor of this particularly garish change.